# Detection range of RFID with RC522/PN532

Tags: raspberry-pi, rfid, nfc

I need to read a tag in a range of about 5 to 10 cm (with 2 thin (~1 cm) layers between, one in plastic, the other in ceramic). I tested two devices: the RFID-RC522 and the PN532 (in NFC mode, reading Felica cards). And for both of them, the maximum range I had, without obstacles, is 5 cm.

I checked on the description of the different frequencies of RFID, and it said that with 13.56 Hz frequency, the range should be between 10 to 100 cm. Why I cannot get at least 10 cm (I mean, is it normal with that *cheap* readers)?

I there a way to increase my range? Hardwarely (new antenna), or softwarely (I'm working on RPi). Or does it exist other RFID readers that could achieve that?

I checked some UHF RFID readers, but it looks like *killing a fly with a tank* to me. I don't need such a huge range. Also, for my application, I would prefer passive tags.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Understanding RFID and RFID Operating Ranges: https://blog.acdist.com/understanding-rfid-and-rfid-operating-ranges．

Comment: Maybe should I consider near-range UHF for my application? I'll look if I can find devices

Comment: Yes, HF/NFC seems good for you.  Good luck and have a great RFID project.